# Exercise in Erdmann's Intro to Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm working on question 4.8 on page 36 of Erdmann and Wildon's book called *Introduction to Lie Algebras*. The question is as follows:

> Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over a field $F$, such that $[a,b],b]=0$ for all $a,b \in L$.
>
> (i) If $Char(F) \neq 3$, then show that $L^3=0$;
>
> (ii) if $F$ has characteristic 3 then show that $L^4=0$. Here $L^k=[L L^{k-1}]$ and $L^1=[L L]$.

Now to the key is to look at $[[a,b+c],b+c]$ and deduce that $[[a,c],b]=-[[a,b],c]$, and then use Jacobi to show that $[[a,b],c]=0$ for all $a,b,c \in L$. But doesn't this mean that $L^2=0$?. I'm just a little worried that I seem to have proven something stronger than the question asks, which makes me uneasy. Similarly for part (ii) I think the proof shows $L^3=0$.

So I was wondering if there is something I am overlooking.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think it means $L^2 = 0$?  You have shown that $[[a, b], c] = 0$ for all $a, b, c \in L$, *not* that $[a, b] = 0$ for all $a, b \in L$.

Comment: My first guess was that the indexing is off by one, because I find it a bit strange that $L^1\neq L$. But according to that definition this may well be the case for many $L$ :-) @Jim: See the strange definition of $L^k$ given in item ii) !

Comment: Yeah well thats the definition he gives in the book for $L^k$

Comment: When talking about lower central series, I believe it to be pretty standard to define it as $L_1 = L$ and $L_k=[L,L_{k-1}]$ for $k\geq2$. Do not get confused with the derived series where $L^1= [L,L]$ and $L^k=[L^{k-1},L^{k-1}]$ for $k\geq2$.

Comment: i.e note their differing starting points! $L^1 = L_2$

Comment: @ChrisBirkbeck The book is by Erdmann *and Wildon*, and Erdmann is a she.

Comment: @mt_ Thanks, I've edited the question now, but I can't see how to edit my comment. At least I know now for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

*This CW answer intends to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As already noted in the comments, you are correct. It seems like the authors themselves got confused with the definitions.