# How to prove this Lie algebra is nilpotent?

Tags: lie-algebras, nilpotence

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over the field $F$ with the property that
$\forall x,y,z\in L ; [[x,y],z]=0$ . How to show that $L^3=0?$ Here $L^3=[L,L^2],L^2=[L,L^1],L^1=[L,L].$

There is no condition on the dimension of the Lie algebra over the field $F,$ $Char(F)\neq 3.$

Help me to solve this .

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: According to me $L^2=0.$ Since $L^1=span\{[x,y]: x,y\in L\} ,$ by the definition of $L^2=span\{[x,[y,z]]:x,y,z\in L\}$ by the hypothesis it's zero . Is it ok?

Comment: Seems fine. Appears to be a typo, possibly related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352344/269764

Comment: Yes yes , thank you.